# Asymptotic approximation of an integral

Tags: definite-integrals, asymptotics

I am trying to determine asymptotic approximation of the following integral as $a \to0$ and $a \to1$.

$$a^2\int_{0}^{\cos^{-1}a} \frac{\sin^2\theta}{{(1-\sin^2\theta)}\sqrt{1-a^2 -\sin^2\theta}} d\theta$$

I simplified using Taylor series for the trigonometric functions and reached to the following point:

$$(1-\epsilon^2)\int_{0}^{\cos^{-1}\sqrt{1-\epsilon^2}} \frac{\theta^2}{\sqrt{\epsilon^2 -\theta^2}} d\theta$$ where $1-\epsilon^2=a^2$

How to proceed from here to get the asymptotic approximations? Any other approach is also welcome.

Comment: Note that $\cos^{-1}\sqrt{1-\epsilon^2} = \sin^{-1}\epsilon$.

Comment: The last integral may be obtained directly through a trig sub.

Comment: @eyeballfrog you are right. But evaluating the integral with this limit is tough.

Comment: Numerically, for $a = 1 - \epsilon$, the integral scales as $(\pi/2)\epsilon$. $a = \epsilon$ is definitely $1 - O(a)$, though I assume you're most interested in what that $O(a)$ actually is.

Comment: @eyeballfrog Yes I am interested in $O(a)$.

Answer (score 4):

By substituting $\theta=\epsilon \sin t\implies d\theta=\epsilon\cos t dt $, the expression turns into $$\epsilon^2(1-\epsilon^2)\int_0^{\sin^{-1} \left(\frac{\sin^{-1} \epsilon }{\epsilon}\right)}\sin^2 t \ dt$$ and using $2\sin^2t =1-\cos 2t$, into $$\frac{\epsilon^2(1-\epsilon^2)}{2}\left [ \sin^{-1} B - B\sqrt{1-B^2} \right] $$ where $B= \frac{\sin^{-1} \epsilon}{\epsilon}$.

Comment: $\cos t$  has to be in the denominator in the first integral and also $2sin^2 t=1-cos2t$

Comment: @nchom The $\cos$ at the top due to $d\theta$ cancels it out.

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to transform the integral into an algebraic function integrated over $(0,\infty)$ that doesn't blow up anywhere. This will hopefully give a nice power series for the integrand where all the integrals converge. For $a\rightarrow 1$, we use
$$
\theta = \cos^{-1}\left(a\sqrt{\frac{1+u^2}{a^2u^2 + 1}}\right)
$$
This particular choice of transformation turns the integral into
$$
\int_{0}^\infty\frac{(1-a^2)du}{(1+u^2)^{3/2}\sqrt{1+u^2a^2}}.
$$
This has a nice power series around $a = 1$ where all the integrals converge, and you can get the asymptotic behavior from that. However, as it happens, WolframAlpha was actually able to do this integral in terms of complete elliptic integrals. Thus, the original integral is equal to
$$
\int_0^{\cos^{-1}a}\frac{a^2\tan^2\theta \,d\theta}{\cos^2\theta - a^2}= E(1-a^2) - a^2K(1-a^2),
$$
and you can also find the power series near $a = 1$ using known power series representations of $E$ and $K$ near zero. In particular, you'll get
$$
\int_0^{\cos^{-1}a}\frac{a^2\tan^2\theta \,d\theta}{\cos^2\theta - a^2}= \frac{\pi}{2}(1-a) + O((1-a)^2)
$$

For $a$ near $0$, we run into the problem that the function isn't analytic near $0$. However, WolframAlpha tells me that we can get the following:
$$
\int_0^{\cos^{-1}a}\frac{a^2\tan^2\theta \,d\theta}{\cos^2\theta - a^2}= 1 -  \frac{a^2}{4}\left(1 -2\ln\left|\frac{a}{4}\right|\right) + O(a^4\ln a)
$$
And presumably the rest of the terms of the series are also of the form $a^{2n}(b + c\ln|a|)$.